# URL Encoding/Decoding

Tags: java, android, url, encode, ansi-escape

I have the string below and I am trying to format it as https://any_site/any_item_picture to be able to download the image from any specific server.

> output=["https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a4ae31fc-572f-45a3-9d2a-4bf311b27e5d_1.ce84f66fa446e24c989f7f43f0a2a665.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=ffffff"

From the original variable, my code below replaces backslashes, and some other characters like "[" to URL scape codes, which I don't need. It also shows an error :

> W/System.err: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ["https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a4ae3

The code is as follows:

```
  @Override
                public void onResponse(String output) {
                    String backslash = output;
                    String imageurl = null;
                    try {
                        imageurl =  URLEncoder.encode(output, "UTF-8");


                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

The response after running the code:

> 22-10-31 15:09:20.472 10428-10428/com.example.weatherapp D/response: %5B%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fi5.walmartimages.com%5C%2Fasr%5C%2Fa4ae31fc-572f-45a3-9d2a-4bf311b27e5d_1.ce84f66fa446e24c989f7f43f0a2a665.jpeg%3FodnHeight%3D450%26odnWidth%3D450%26odnBg%3Dffffff

Can anyone please, point in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. It seems to be not much to do with encoding but removing a lot of cruft from a variable value to leave you with a usable url... `v = v.replaceAll(".*(https.*)", "$1") ;` would be a crude way of approaching it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract the url first and then encode it. Encoding will not change your string. URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the network.

```
        public static void  main(String[] args) {
            List<String> extractedUrls = extractUrls("output=[\"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a4ae31fc-572f-45a3-9d2a-4bf311b27e5d_1.ce84f66fa446e24c989f7f43f0a2a665.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=ffffff\"");
    
            for (String url : extractedUrls)
            {
                System.out.println("url " + url);
                try {
                    System.out.println("encodedUrl " + URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8"));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    
        public static List<String> extractUrls(String text)
        {
            List<String> containedUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
            String urlRegex = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher urlMatcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    
            while (urlMatcher.find())
            {
                containedUrls.add(text.substring(urlMatcher.start(0),
                        urlMatcher.end(0)));
            }
    
            return containedUrls;
        }
```

Output:

> url
> https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a4ae31fc-572f-45a3-9d2a-4bf311b27e5d_1.ce84f66fa446e24c989f7f43f0a2a665.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=ffffff
>
> encodedUrl
> https%3A%2F%2Fi5.walmartimages.com%2Fasr%2Fa4ae31fc-572f-45a3-9d2a-4bf311b27e5d_1.ce84f66fa446e24c989f7f43f0a2a665.jpeg%3FodnHeight%3D450%26odnWidth%3D450%26odnBg%3Dffffff